# Change the colour from Gantt digram via JavaScript

Tags: gantt-view

I'm quite new here an I would like to know how I could change the colour from the bar in the gantt daigramm via JavaScript von "green" to "blue", but I need a specific blue.

How can I do that?

I would very thankful for your fast help!

Best regards

Matthias